# Primefaces tabChange notification

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

We use PrimeFaces 3.3.1, Mojarra 2.1.10 and Tomcat 7.0.26.

All components in our application are created programmatically and only the root component on the page is bound. This is the page -- part of the template -- with binding to the root component, Panel called rootPanel:

```xml
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:porta="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/porta"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

   <ui:define name="body">
      <h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="message" />
      <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
                    onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />

      <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header=".::."
                draggable="false" closable="false">
         <p:graphicImage value="/img/progressbar.gif" />
      </p:dialog>

      <h:form id="initForm" name="initform">
         <p:panel id="rootPanelId" binding="#{applicationErp.rootPanel}" 
                  rendered="true">
         </p:panel>
       </h:form>
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This is how we created TabView compoment programmatically:

```java
mainTabbedPane = new TabView();
mainTabbedPane.setId("formErpMainTabViewId");
mainTabbedPane.setStyle("height: 100%; width: 100%;");

AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
MethodExpression methodExpression = FacesUtil.createMethodExpression("#{formerpmain.tabChanged}", Void.class, new Class<?>[]{TabChangeEvent.class});

ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(methodExpression));
ajaxBehavior.setListener(methodExpression);
ajaxBehavior.setUpdate(":initForm:formErpMainTabViewId");

mainTabbedPane.addClientBehavior("tabChange",ajaxBehavior);
```

This is tabChanged method:

```java
public void tabChanged(TabChangeEvent event){
  requestPartialRendering();
}
```

Method tabChanged, specified in MethodExpression above, never get called on tab change. Is this right way to specify method to be called on tab change? How to specify bean method to be called on tab changed?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to create the component programmatically?

Comment: Yes, it is. We are builing ERP system. We use abstract classes where we specify layout, factory methods for components and etc. We also have specific classes that extend these abstract classes for variuos platforms, Swing, Android, PrimeFaces(Web). This approach allows us to have rapid development and easy changes on all these platforms.

Answer (score 1):

After few days of experimenting we have found solution. We set "@parent" value to setProcess method, only that value works and remove TabChangedEvent from MethodExpression's argument's list. Afte these changes it works fine.

Code:

```java
AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
MethodExpression methodExpression = FacesUtil.createMethodExpression(
        "#{formerpmain.onTabChange}", void.class, new Class<?>[]{});

ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(
        new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(methodExpression));
ajaxBehavior.setListener(methodExpression);
ajaxBehavior.setProcess("@parent");
```